# Crash while performing fetch request -[NSTemporaryObjectID_default compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am facing a strange issue. While unit testing Core data code, it crashes at (try fetchController.performFetch()). Unit test passes when run individually, but it fails when run in batches. I am using inMemory store type for unit testing. Any help please?

```
   let fetchRequest = T.fetchRequest()
   fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "objectID", ascending: false)]
   let fetchController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                    managedObjectContext: self,
                                                    sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                    cacheName: nil)

    self.performAndWait {
        do {
            try fetchController.performFetch()
        } catch (let exception) {
            error = exception
        }
    }
```

The error message is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTemporaryObjectID_default compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b0800086e40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011632a29b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011531d735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116348fa4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011632efb6 ___forwarding___ + 1446
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116330e88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x0000000114da9bd0 _NSCompareObject + 46
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011629b39b __CFSimpleMergeSort + 75
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011629adf8 CFSortIndexes + 808
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011629be0e CFMergeSortArray + 334
    9   Foundation                          0x0000000114daa2dd _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 615
    10  Foundation                          0x0000000114daa5b7 -[NSArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:] + 531
    11  CoreData                            0x0000000115c71baa -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 4746
    12  CoreData                            0x0000000115e27372 __43-[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:]_block_invoke + 450
    13  CoreData                            0x0000000115d913f9 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 201
    14  libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib 0x00000001115855f2 _ZN6__tsanL22dispatch_callback_wrapEPv + 306
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118d2e587 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118d3af87 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 94
    17  libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib 0x0000000111585980 wrap_dispatch_sync_f + 208
    18  CoreData                            0x0000000115d7b8f6 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator performBlockAndWait:] + 198
    19  CoreData                            0x0000000115cb42d1 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 161
    20  CoreData                            0x0000000115cb41af -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 239
    21  CoreData                            0x0000000115e27751 -[NSFetchedResultsController _recursivePerformBlockAndWait:withContext:] + 145
    22  CoreData                            0x0000000115cb42d1 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 161
    23  CoreData                            0x0000000115cb41af -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 239
    24  CoreData                            0x0000000115e27751 -[NSFetchedResultsController _recursivePerformBlockAndWait:withContext:] + 145
    25  CoreData                            0x0000000115e270db -[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:] + 299
    26  C4M                                 0x000000010f6c5482 $sSo22NSManagedObjectContextC10RxCoreDataE16performSyncFetchySo26NSFetchedResultsControllerCySo20NSFetchRequestResult_pG_s5Error_pSgtxmSo0aB0CRbzlFyyXEfU_ + 194
    27  C4M                                 0x000000010f6c59cc $sSo22NSManagedObjectContextC10RxCoreDataE16performSyncFetchySo26NSFetchedResultsControllerCySo20NSFetchRequestResult_pG_s5Error_pSgtxmSo0aB0CRbzlFyyXEfU_TA + 44
    28  C4M                                 0x000000010f6c5ae8 $sIg_Ieg_TR + 40
    29  C4M                                 0x000000010f6c5b7c $sIg_Ieg_TRTA + 44
    30  C4M                                 0x000000010f6c5c00 $sIeg_IyB_TR + 80
    31  CoreData                            0x0000000115cb42d1 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 161
    32  libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib 0x00000001115855f2 _ZN6__tsanL22dispatch_callback_wrapEPv + 306
    33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118d2e587 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118d3af87 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 94
    35  libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib 0x0000000111585980 wrap_dispatch_sync_f + 208
    36  CoreData                            0x0000000115cb41de -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 286
    37  C4M                                 0x000000010f6c5079 $sSo22NSManagedObjectContextC10RxCoreDataE16performSyncFetchySo26NSFetchedResultsControllerCySo20NSFetchRequestResult_pG_s5Error_pSgtxmSo0aB0CRbzlF + 1193
    38  C4M                                 0x000000010f6c48af $sSo22NSManagedObjectContextC10RxCoreData0d7ManagedbC0A2cDP16performSyncFetchySo26NSFetchedResultsControllerCySo20NSFetchRequestResult_pG_s5Error_pSgtqd__mSo0aB0CRbd__lFTW + 63
    39  C4M                                 0x000000010f6b7f4c $s10RxCoreData0C5StackC7objectsyAA07ResultsC0CyxGxmKSo15NSManagedObjectCRbzlF + 348
    40  C4M                                 0x000000010f6b7d3a $s10RxCoreData0C5StackCAA0cD8ProtocolA2aDP7objectsyAA07ResultsC0Cyqd__Gqd__mKSo15NSManagedObjectCRbd__lFTW + 74
    41  C4M                                 0x000000010ed8b4a0 $s3C4M10NetworkDAOC16fetchAllNetworks9projectId10onCompleteySS_ySayAA0B0CG_s5Error_pSgtctFy10RxCoreData0N13StackProtocol_pSgcfU_ + 1088
    42  C4M                                 0x000000010ed8baf9 $s3C4M10NetworkDAOC16fetchAllNetworks9projectId10onCompleteySS_ySayAA0B0CG_s5Error_pSgtctFy10RxCoreData0N13StackProtocol_pSgcfU_TA + 57
    43  C4MTests                            0x0000000131672acc $s8C4MTests14MockNetworkDAOC13loadDataStack9modelName9storeType6bundle6onLoadySS_06RxCoreG005StoreL0OSo8NSBundleCyAI0gH8Protocol_pSgctFyAO_s5Error_pSgtcfU_ + 204
    44  C4MTests                            0x0000000131672b89 $s8C4MTests14MockNetworkDAOC13loadDataStack9modelName9storeType6bundle6onLoadySS_06RxCoreG005StoreL0OSo8NSBundleCyAI0gH8Protocol_pSgctFyAO_s5Error_pSgtcfU_TA + 57
    45  C4M                                 0x000000010eff58b9 $s3C4M16DataStackManagerC9modelName4type6bundle10onCompleteACSS_06RxCoreB09StoreTypeOSo8NSBundleCyAH0bC8Protocol_pSg_s5Error_pSgtctcfc + 1753
    46  C4M                                 0x000000010eff51a5 $s3C4M16DataStackManagerC9modelName4type6bundle10onCompleteACSS_06RxCoreB09StoreTypeOSo8NSBundleCyAH0bC8Protocol_pSg_s5Error_pSgtctcfC + 117
    47  C4MTests                            0x00000001316727ac $s8C4MTests14MockNetworkDAOC13loadDataStack9modelName9storeType6bundle6onLoadySS_06RxCoreG005StoreL0OSo8NSBundleCyAI0gH8Protocol_pSgctF + 940
    48  C4M                                 0x000000010e9afe4a $s3C4M16DataAccessObjectCAA0bcD8ProtocolA2aDP04loadB5Stack9modelName9storeType6bundle6onLoadySS_06RxCoreB005StoreK0OSo8NSBundleCyAK0bgE0_pSgctFTW + 154
    49  C4M                                 0x000000010e9aef1f $s3C4M24DataAccessObjectProtocolPAAE04loadB5Stack9modelName9storeType6bundle6onLoadySS_06RxCoreB005StoreK0OSo8NSBundleCyAI0bgE0_pSgctF + 463
    50  C4M                                 0x000000010ed8affd $s3C4M10NetworkDAOC16fetchAllNetworks9projectId10onCompleteySS_ySayAA0B0CG_s5Error_pSgtctF + 605
    51  C4MTests                            0x00000001318d2eca $s8C4MTests14NetworkDOTestsC011testZCreateC8_SuccessyyFy0A1M0C0CSg_AE0C11AccessErrorOSgtcfU_ + 1098
    52  C4MTests                            0x00000001318d2fb9 $s8C4MTests14NetworkDOTestsC011testZCreateC8_SuccessyyFy0A1M0C0CSg_AE0C11AccessErrorOSgtcfU_TA + 57
    53  C4M                                 0x000000010ed89913 $s3C4M10NetworkDAOC6create4name9projectId10onCompleteySS_SSyAA0B0CSg_AA0B11AccessErrorOSgtctFy10RxCoreData0N13StackProtocol_pSgcfU_yyXEfU_ + 1075
    54  C4M                                 0x000000010ed899a6 $s3C4M10NetworkDAOC6create4name9projectId10onCompleteySS_SSyAA0B0CSg_AA0B11AccessErrorOSgtctFy10RxCoreData0N13StackProtocol_pSgcfU_yyXEfU_TA + 70
    55  C4M                                 0x000000010f6b762f $s10RxCoreData0C5StackC5write_13notifyOnWriteyyyXE_SbtKF + 271
    56  C4M                                 0x000000010f6b7492 $s10RxCoreData0C5StackCAA0cD8ProtocolA2aDP5write_13notifyOnWriteyyyXE_SbtKFTW + 82
    57  C4M                                 0x000000010f6b512b $s10RxCoreData0C13StackProtocolPAAE5write_13notifyOnWriteyyyXE_SbtKF + 283
    58  C4M                                 0x000000010ed89047 $s3C4M10NetworkDAOC6create4name9projectId10onCompleteySS_SSyAA0B0CSg_AA0B11AccessErrorOSgtctFy10RxCoreData0N13StackProtocol_pSgcfU_ + 1191
    59  C4M                                 0x000000010ed8937a $s3C4M10NetworkDAOC6create4name9projectId10onCompleteySS_SSyAA0B0CSg_AA0B11AccessErrorOSgtctFy10RxCoreData0N13StackProtocol_pSgcfU_TA + 74
    60  C4MTests                            0x0000000131672acc $s8C4MTests14MockNetworkDAOC13loadDataStack9modelName9storeType6bundle6onLoadySS_06RxCoreG005StoreL0OSo8NSBundleCyAI0gH8Protocol_pSgctFyAO_s5Error_pSgtcfU_ + 204
    61  C4MTests                            0x0000000131672b89 $s8C4MTests14MockNetworkDAOC13loadDataStack9modelName9storeType6bundle6onLoadySS_06RxCoreG005StoreL0OSo8NSBundleCyAI0gH8Protocol_pSgctFyAO_s5Error_pSgtcfU_TA + 57
    62  C4M                                 0x000000010eff58b9 $s3C4M16DataStackManagerC9modelName4type6bundle10onCompleteACSS_06RxCoreB09StoreTypeOSo8NSBundleCyAH0bC8Protocol_pSg_s5Error_pSgtctcfc + 1753
    63  C4M                                 0x000000010eff51a5 $s3C4M16DataStackManagerC9modelName4type6bundle10onCompleteACSS_06RxCoreB09StoreTypeOSo8NSBundleCyAH0bC8Protocol_pSg_s5Error_pSgtctcfC + 117
    64  C4MTests                            0x00000001316727ac $s8C4MTests14MockNetworkDAOC13loadDataStack9modelName9storeType6bundle6onLoadySS_06RxCoreG005StoreL0OSo8NSBundleCyAI0gH8Protocol_pSgctF + 940
    65  C4M                                 0x000000010e9afe4a $s3C4M16DataAccessObjectCAA0bcD8ProtocolA2aDP04loadB5Stack9modelName9storeType6bundle6onLoadySS_06RxCoreB005StoreK0OSo8NSBundleCyAK0bgE0_pSgctFTW + 154
    66  C4M                                 0x000000010e9aef1f $s3C4M24DataAccessObjectProtocolPAAE04loadB5Stack9modelName9storeType6bundle6onLoadySS_06RxCoreB005StoreK0OSo8NSBundleCyAI0bgE0_pSgctF + 463
    67  C4M                                 0x000000010ed88b43 $s3C4M10NetworkDAOC6create4name9projectId10onCompleteySS_SSyAA0B0CSg_AA0B11AccessErrorOSgtctF + 755
    68  C4MTests                            0x00000001318d28de $s8C4MTests14NetworkDOTestsC011testZCreateC8_SuccessyyF + 830
    69  C4MTests                            0x00000001318d3e95 $s8C4MTests14NetworkDOTestsC011testZCreateC8_SuccessyyFTo + 85
    70  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011633111c __invoking___ + 140
    71  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011632e5b5 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 325
    72  XCTest                              0x000000012de4a821 __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke.208 + 78
    73  XCTest                              0x000000012dea49b9 -[XCTestCase(Failures) performFailableBlock:testCaseRun:shouldInterruptTest:] + 57
    74  XCTest                              0x000000012dea48d7 -[XCTestCase(Failures) _performTurningExceptionsIntoFailuresInterruptAfterHandling:block:] + 96
    75  XCTest                              0x000000012de4a30a __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke + 1153
    76  XCTest                              0x000000012de49de2 -[XCTestCase testContextPerformInScope:] + 211
    77  XCTest                              0x000000012de49e7c -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 137
    78  XCTest                              0x000000012de4bbed __26-[XCTestCase performTest:]_block_invoke_2 + 43
    79  XCTest                              0x000000012dea49b9 -[XCTestCase(Failures) performFailableBlock:testCaseRun:shouldInterruptTest:] + 57
    80  XCTest                              0x000000012dea48d7 -[XCTestCase(Failures) _performTurningExceptionsIntoFailuresInterruptAfterHandling:block:] + 96
    81  XCTest                              0x000000012de4bb04 __26-[XCTestCase performTest:]_block_invoke.334 + 88
    82  XCTest                              0x000000012deb8302 +[XCTContext runInContextForTestCase:block:] + 219
    83  XCTest                              0x000000012de4b273 -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 668
    84  XCTest                              0x000000012de90807 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
    85  XCTest                              0x000000012de4584a __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 365
    86  XCTest                              0x000000012de44f74 -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 54
    87  XCTest                              0x000000012de45271 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 355
    88  XCTest                              0x000000012de90807 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
    89  XCTest                              0x000000012de4584a __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 365
    90  XCTest                              0x000000012de44f74 -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 54
    91  XCTest                              0x000000012de45271 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 355
    92  XCTest                              0x000000012de90807 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
    93  XCTest                              0x000000012de4584a __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 365
    94  XCTest                              0x000000012de44f74 -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 54
    95  XCTest                              0x000000012de45271 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 355
    96  XCTest                              0x000000012de90807 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
    97  XCTest                              0x000000012dec728e __44-[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:]_block_invoke + 171
    98  XCTest                              0x000000012dec7391 __44-[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:]_block_invoke.84 + 118
    99  XCTest                              0x000000012de5f593 -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] + 588
    100 XCTest                              0x000000012dec704d -[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:] + 623
    101 XCTest                              0x000000012de28dd7 -[XCTestDriver runTestsAndReturnError:] + 456
    102 XCTest                              0x000000012deb4554 _XCTestMain + 2484
    103 libXCTestBundleInject.dylib         0x00000001123f3be7 __copy_helper_block_e8_32s + 0
    104 CoreFoundation                      0x000000011628da3c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    105 CoreFoundation                      0x000000011628d1f0 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 336
    106 CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116287a64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1284
    107 CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116287221 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    108 GraphicsServices                    0x000000011b8df1dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    109 UIKitCore                           0x000000011ec9e115 UIApplicationMain + 140
    110 C4M                                 0x000000010eddf473 main + 99
    111 libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000118d9e551 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: My guess is that the in memory store doesn’t like the sort descriptor based on objectID.

Comment: I tried the same thing and can't reproduce the crash. It might help if you could edit the question to include more detail.